# Some glossary (acronym) entries without location (but still with links)

Tags: hyperref, glossaries, acronyms

In my master thesis, I have a lots of acronyms. Some of them I use very frequently, while others just once or twice. Some of them I have a "main" definition, most don't have one. (Main definition is `\gls[format=hyperbf, counter=subsection]{ACRO})`.

So far, for each entry, the location list is the list of all pages where it appears (italic) plus a list of the subsections where it's main definition appears (bold). Everytime, all acronyms in the text have hyperlinks.

What I would like is to get rid of the pages in the location list, but not the "main" definition, but still keep the hyperlinks.

So is it possible to have a command that adds nothing to the location list (like `\glsentrytext`, NOT like `\gls`) but still has an hyperlink (NOT like `\glsentrytext`, like `\gls`)?

Or, in other words, is there a command that behaves exactly like `\gls{ACRO}` but that does not add any location (page, section, ...) to the list of location of the ACRO entry?

---

## * Edit 1:

As said in glossaries-user.pdf and glossaries.pdf, I tried to add in the preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\glshyperlink}[2][\glsentryname{\@glo@label}]{%
\def\@glo@label{#2}%
\@glslink{glo:#2}{#1}}
```

With the intention to test it first as is, and then replace `\glsentryname` with `\gls`. However, I get this error:

```
! Use of \@ doesn't match its definition.
\\glshyperlink [#1]#2->\def \@glo@label{#2}\@gls
                                                link{glo:#2}{#1}
l.37 here on the \glshyperlink{rhs}
                                    of this equation is the definition of th...

? h
If you say, e.g., `\def\a1{...}', then you must always
put `1' after `\a', since control sequence names are
made up of letters only. The macro here has not been
followed by the required stuff, so I'm ignoring it.

?
```

**Any Idea?**

---

## * MWE:

I'd like to have exactly the same but with no page numbers in the list of acronyms (only the subsection references).

```
% If file save under 'mwe.tex', then compile it:

% pdflatex mwe
% makeglossarie mwe
% pdflatex mwe
% makeglossarie mwe
% pdflatex mwe
% pdflatex mwe

\documentclass[pdftex, letterpaper, 12pt, ]{article}

\usepackage[pdftex, breaklinks=true, ]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym, style=super3colheader, counter=page, hyperfirst=true, ]{glossaries} 
\makeglossaries

\renewcommand*{\pagelistname}{Location \\ }
\renewcommand*{\glsnumberformat}[1]{\textit{#1}}

\newacronym{rhs}{rhs}{right hand side}
\newacronym{lhs}{lhs}{left hand side}
\newacronym{RMS}{RMS}{Root-Mean-Square}
\newacronym{ESA}{ESA}{European Space Agency}

\begin{document}

\glsaddall

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, style=long3colheader, numberedsection=false, nonumberlist=false, ]

\section{Test}

\subsection{Blah}
here on the \gls{rhs} of this equation is the definition of the \gls[format=hyperbf, counter=subsection]{RMS}) that is given by the \gls*{ESA}.

\subsection{One more time}
here on the \gls{rhs} of this equation is the definition of the \gls[format=hyperbf, counter=subsection]{RMS}) that is given by the \gls*{ESA}.

\end{document}
```

---

## * PDF File produced:

[image: PDF File produced]

Comment: Put the three lines you added between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, after the idea from Holle, and some digging in both `glossaries-user.pdf` and `glossaries.pdf`, plus some LaTeX error googling, here is the solution, that works really nicely:

In you preamble, add:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\glshyperlink}[2][\gls{\@glo@label}]{%
\def\@glo@label{#2}%
\@glslink{glo:#2}{#1}}
\makeatother
```

And you're good to go :)

(Edit: it obviously screws a bit things up if you have the `[hyperfirst=false]` option)

Answer (score 1):

Just have a look to the `\glshyperlink` command. It creates a link to the glossary but without putting any information to this. See 'glossaries-user.pdf' at page 59.